# how to access to raw cert chain of an SSL server?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I know how to get the cert chain presented by a server with

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.domain:portnum <<<''
```

But, what openssl prints is the "reconstructed" cert chain, not the raw one. If the certs are presented in another order, openssl will reorder them prior to showing them. Also if there are exra certificates, it will skip them.

I'd like to access the unprocessed list of certs that the server presents.

Is this possible, and how ?

Comment: As long as you're expecting TLS < 1.3 then you could watch/capture them with a network monitoring tool such as WireShark.

Comment: Or better, how about this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/931761/227877

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I tried other tools. wireshark, well, not quite what I am looking for, but would certainly work, as a last resort. keytool is not just the right tool I'm looking for. It does not eliminate extra certs, but moves them near the end. so close...

In fact, gnutls-cli did the job for me

```
gnutls-cli --print-cert server.domain:port
```

Thanks again @garethTheRed for the suggestions. I had only openssl in mind and the key was to try something else.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by the way.

Comment: didn't know, didn't dare. Thought it would be "cheating".  I'll know for the next time. thks again